# Can I Send Instant Message and Call using Lync 2013 SDK OR API in WPF Application?

Tags: lync

I want to create a sample app, from this app user can able to sned IM and call to another person. So just i want to know like can i integrate my windows/WPF application with Lync SDK 2013 or Lync APP.

or which one is better SDK or API?

Answer (score 0):

The API builds on top of an already installed Lync client on a user's computer. This is the way to go if you install your WPF application on computers where you know the user already has a Lync install. You can control the Lync client from your own application, and is by far the easiest way to set up calls because the interface is already there.

If the application will be deployed for users who do not have Lync client installed, you have two options:

- Use the SDK (assuming you mean UCMA). It is a little more low-level and allows you to connect to and communicate with Lync servers without having a Lync client running in the background. Create your own interface for chat and audio.
- Create a client for [UCWA](https://ucwa.lync.com/), the web services based connection. For audio, UCWA supports "Phone Audio", ie it will call you on a number you supply and then connect you to the person you wanted to call.